# LESS used in conjunction with culture codes

Tags: .net, css, less

I am build a site that is multi-lingual and need to switch out some css on a page to handle different languages.  I am pasing the culture-code  into the page and I am looking for a way to use it to reference a different selector that would be used only for that language.I was wondering has anybody ever used LESS for this purpose.  If you have any tips or tutorials, please post.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it for this internationalization. But you can easily style things by adding your `.culture-code` class to the `<html>` element:

```
 /* default */
 body {
  background:white;
 }

/* these only apply to the body element when your culture code class is applied to the page */
.culture-code body {
  background:red;
}
.culture-code-2 body {
  background:blue;
}
```

If you are going to have *very* different stylesheets for each culture-code, you could create different less stylesheets, name them after the culture-code, and then use your backend language to import that stylesheet. But, hopefully you are only performing minor tweaks : )